# How to run a script BEFORE gnome session logoff

Tags: gnome, scripts, gdm, logout

I have seen many posts on how to utilize <gdmconfdir>/PostLogin/Default to run scripts whenever a user logs out of his/her X session. However, from the [documentation](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en) I understand that this script is run AFTER the X-session has terminated.

I need to run a script BEFORE the X-session terminates (specifically, I need to shut down a VirtualBox session with a guest OS in it before the logoff process kills the VirtualBox process).

What (if any) is the appropriate way to do this

// FvW

Comment: Would it be OK to replace the normal shutdown/reboot/logout button with a desktop file, that does the tasks in correct order? The desktop file can be started via an icon/button in a good location, so that you can use it in a convenient way.

Comment: That might be a last resort kind of thing, but if there is a more elegant option (which there may not be) that would have my preference.